# query rows that are matched to one or more criteria of field

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to select the rows that are matched with the one or more criteria.

**Example Table and data**

```
#ID #NAME #KEYWORDS(Varchar)


1 BBC   news,finance

2 CNN   music,finance,sports

3 CNBC  music,sports,finance
```

User search criteria will be `sports,finance` **(can be more than one keywords separated by comma)** which I prepare into list of keywords string before I query.

When I use the **sql (1)** like below, it only selects CNN and CNBC.

```
SELECT * from channel where Keywords LIKE '%sports%' OR '%finance%';
```

But when I use the **sql(2**) like below, show BBC,CNN, CNBC.

```
SELECT * from channel where Keywords LIKE '%finance%' OR '%sports%'
```

My requirement is I want to select all the rows that are matched the keywords (in the above example: sports,finance should get BBC,CNN and CNBC as all of three have finance).

As user inputs will be a String(sports,finance,etc) , I am just making an query based on the varied input.

Comment: You database engine INNODB or MYISAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('finance', keywords) or
      FIND_IN_SET('sports', keywords)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1975d/3)

or using `LIKE`

```
SELECT * 
from table1 
where Keywords LIKE '%sports%' OR 
      Keywords LIKE '%finance%'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1975d/4)

Answer (score 1):

Better to use the Union query Than OR. multiple Or query take more time to perform.

```
SELECT *
FROM channel
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('finance', keywords) 
UNION
SELECT *
FROM channel
      FIND_IN_SET('sports', keywords)
```